# How to get current value from django table

Tags: python, django

I am only getting the last value from my django table after clicking the delete button.

html file -

```
<body>

  <div class="for-body">
    <!-- test table -->
    <form method="POST" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      
      <input id="label" name="engname" value="{{ eng_name }}">{{ eng_name }}</input>
      <button name="update" class="add-button" type="submit"><b>Update</b></button>
      <button name="add" class="add-button1" type="submit"><b>Add Existing User</b></button>

    
    
    
      <tbody class="for-tbody1">
          <tr class="for-tr1">
            <td class="for-td1">
              <dh-components-grid-body-render class="for-dhcomp">
                <div class="for-div1">
                  <table class="for-table1" id="pgnum">
                    <thead class="for-thead1">
                        <tr class="for-tr2">
                        <td class="for-td2"><div class="dh-grid-headers-cell-default">User</div></td>
                        <td class="for-td2"><div class="dh-grid-headers-cell-default">Email</div></td>
                        <td class="for-td2"><div class="dh-grid-headers-cell-default">Role</div></td>
                        <td class="for-td2"><div class="dh-grid-headers-cell-default">Remove</div></td>                          
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody class="for-tbody2">

                     
                      <tr class="for-tr3">
                        {% for i in user_list %}
                        <td class="for-td3"><div class="cell-default-style">{{i.first_name}} {{i.last_name}}</div></td>
                        <td class="for-td3"><div class="cell-default-style"><input type="hidden" value="{{ i.email }}" name="email">{{i.email}}</input></div></td>
                        {% if i.is_superuser == True %}
                        <td class="for-td3"><div class="cell-default-style">Super User</div></td>
                        {% elif i.is_staff == True %}                           
                        <td class="for-td3"><div class="cell-default-style">Admin</div></td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td class="for-td3"><div class="cell-default-style">Practitioner</div></td>
                        {% endif %}
                        <td class="for-td3"><div class="cell-default-style"><button class="btn" name="delete" type="submit"><img src="/static/assets/images/trash1.png" style="width: 18px;" alt="Delete"></button></div></td>
                      </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                  
                    
                    </tbody>
                    
                  </table>
                </div>
              </dh-components-grid-body-render>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

views.py -

```
def engagement_admin_edit(request, id):
staff = request.user.is_staff
a = User.is_authenticated

if staff == True:
    eng_list = Grp.objects.all()
    eng = Grp.objects.get(id = id)
    eng_name = eng.gname
    eng_name = str(eng_name)
    eng_id = eng.id
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM main_enguser WHERE eid=%s''',[eng_id])
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    users = []
    for i in row:
        users.append(i[1])
    user_list = User.objects.filter(email__in=users)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'update' in request.POST:
            name = (request.POST.get('engname'))
            if name != eng_name:
                engid = eng.id
                engid = int(engid)
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute('''UPDATE main_grp SET gname=%s WHERE id=%s''',[name,engid])
                messages.success(request, 'Engagement Name Updated Successfully')
                return redirect('/eng_admin')
            else:
                print("There")
                messages.success(request, 'No Changes Detected')
                return redirect('/eng_admin')
        if 'delete' in request.POST:
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            print("HI")
            print(email)
            messages.success(request, 'No Changes Detected')
    return render(request, "main/admin_eng_edit.html", {'eng_name':eng_name, 'user':users, 'user_list':user_list})
```

in views.py the main part is:

```
if 'delete' in request.POST:
email = request.POST.get('email', '')
print("HI")
print(email)
```

The script only prints last row's email id even if the first row's delete button is clicked.
tried request.POST.get('email') as well.
tried changing the  tags position.
But it did not help
Any sort of help is appreciated! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML form can not provide the data from multiple fields of the same name.

However, you can pass a value inside your submit button, using "value" HTML attribute

Try something like that:

```
<button class="btn" name="delete" type="submit" value="{{ i.email }}"><img src="/static/assets/images/trash1.png" style="width: 18px;" alt="Delete"></button>
```

and then in your code:

```
email = request.POST.get('delete', '')
```

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as a correct answer then?